# Equivalence of if-then and implies in OCL statements

Tags: ocl, formal-methods, post-conditions

Are the following two OCL statements equivalent for some function context?

`post: if a > 0 then b < c`

`post: b < c implies a > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

In OCL, the construct is `if` ... `then` ... `else` ... `endif` so your first example can only be 'equivalent' to a different syntax error.

The logical operations are rewritable using `if` constructs, but considerable care is necessary to ensure that the possibilities with null or invalid inputs do not crash the `if` condition term which must be a 2-valued `Boolean`.

Comment: Subsidiary question: if the syntax was correct, and looking at the implication [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional), wouldn't `post: if a > 0 then b < c else true endif` be equivalent to `post: a > 0 implies b < c` or `post: a <= 0 implies b >= c` ?   and not `post: b < c implies a > 0`?

Comment: Looks plausible. Arguably the use of multiple invaraints (pre/postconditions) is just an editorial choice that improves readbility. Once an implmenetation starts considering avoiding redundancy via Common Subexepression Elimination, it is clear that an efficient evaluation will prioritize and merge the multiples in a single constraint that shares wherever possible.